# Css file not showing when calling from php include funciton

Tags: php, html, css

I created a webpage with a dynamic footer. In the footer I have a facebook icon. when I preview the page the image does not appear. All other css files are working fine except for the footer. Could anyone tell me what I am missing?

My footer template:

```
<footer>
        <div class="icon-text">
            <div class="icon-text-text">
                <ul class="footer-nav">
                    <li><a href="tearms.php">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shipping_info">Shipping Information</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-text">
                <p class="email_text">Follow me on</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="social-icon" src=../icons/facebook.png" 
alt="Facebook">
                </a>
    </footer>
    <footer class="second">
        <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
    <!--End of Footer Section-->
```

Here is my css for the footer section:

```
footer  {
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    width: 1350px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.icon-text {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-text-text {
    font-size: 150%;    
}
img.social-icon {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}
.email_text {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

And here in the php on the index page to add  the footer:

```
<?php include_once("templates/template_footer.php"); ?>
```

There are other things wrong with the footer like I can't get the wording to move to the left but the image is whats important. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Other than the fact the the `src` attribute of your image is not properly quoted, you're also using relative path for your image, which may not resolve to the correct path to your image location depends on which part of your website you're on.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your file tree ?

Comment: Yeah as @ChanMT mentioned above, you haven't specified image path correctly. Also, try not to style semantic tags and wrap your content with a new div tags and style through the div instead for the best styling practice.

Comment: @terryeah there is **nothing** wrong with styling semantic elements. What shouldn't be done is adding a semantic element purely for styling purposes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550026/4665 . Why add extra elements when what you have is enough.

Comment: @JonP You might be right and I might be wrong but please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144965/7032438 . This is exactly the same as how I thought of styling semantic elements.

Comment: The image is in an icon folder one directory back so I use the ../ to go back to it. If this is not correct how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your path was correct, Please check it out.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php include_once('templates/template_footer.php'); ?>">
```